# Close similar questions or answer with links to existing answers

Tags: discussion

As spring arrives in the Northern Hemisphere we are starting to see [questions](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/saving-an-unattended-yard) [from](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5841/what-can-i-do-this-spring-to-help-my-new-lawn) [first](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/lawn-repair-treatment-ahead-of-spring) time users that have, in many respects, been asked and answered before.

The choices are to answer the question by repeating the fundamentals, vote to close the question as a duplicate or....

For first time users we want them to come back so closing the question would not be perceived as very friendly.  Yet what I see as a virtue of Stack Overflow: having one really good answer to a question can be overwhelmed by having numerous answers to the same question.

Unlike our technically minded forums the pace of horticulture is much slower.  The key to a good lawn today is the same as last year or ten years ago.

What is the best solution to providing a good answer without repeating yourself and respecting a new users question?

Answer (score 4):

If the question is a duplicate, then we can vote to close it. Just casting a single close vote will put it in the close votes queue where it can be addressed by other top rep users or moderators.

If it's not a duplicate then we need to go ahead and try to answer fully as best we can, Maybe just with a quotation from the other answer, a link to it and a paragraph or so that tailors the answer to the specific needs of that particular post.

We want all of your non-duplicate, constructive, real questions to get answers even if they require some duplication. But if they fall into any of those categories we can safely close them.